# Destructor called after operator= in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, destructor

I have a class whose members are somewhat as follows

```
CRectangle CRectangle::operator+ (CRectangle param) {
    CRectangle temp;
    temp.width = new int;
    temp.height = new int;
    *temp.width = *width + *param.width;
    *temp.height = *height + *param.height;
    return (temp);
}

CRectangle& CRectangle::operator= (CRectangle param) {
    *width =  *param.width;
    *height = *param.height;
    return *this;
}

CRectangle::~CRectangle () {
    n--;
    delete width;
    delete height;
}
```

Now if i do

```
CRectangle a(3, 4), b(5, 6), c;
cout << b.area() << endl; // gives 30
c = a + b;
cout << b.area() << endl; // gives random value
```

then destructor is called on object `b` too. I mean, it should be called on temp, but why on `b`?
Is this related to how i am passing the parameters?

Comment: The lifetime of the members width and height are not the same as the lifetime of CRectange, which can cause all kinds of obscure memory problems. Use 'int' as the type of width and height instead of int* to simplify your code. You dont need the new int and delete width/height anymore. This probably fixes the problem as well.

Comment: actually i m just testing the destructor functionality... So, i wrote the code this way

Comment: I guess you haven't written a copy constructor. Testing destructor functionality without a valid copy constructor is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: m new to oops in c++, can you guide me a little?

Comment: Correct way to add an addition operator to the classes like yours is adding an operator overload of signature of `const CRectangle operator+(const CRectangle& lhs, const CRectangle& rhs);` as a global function. And if that function needs to access private members of parameters, declare it `friend`.

Comment: google rule of three c++ -- without that fundamental change other changes are bandaids.  You need to implement or disable your copy and or move constructors.

Comment: It's also on SO: [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator+` receives copy of the argument passed to it.

```
    CRectangle CRectangle::operator+ (CRectangle param) {
        CRectangle temp;
        temp.width = new int;
        temp.height = new int;
        *temp.width = *width + *param.width;
        *temp.height = *height + *param.height;
        return (temp);
    }
```

In the code:

```
CRectangle a(3,4),b(5,6),c;
c=a+b;
```

More specifically, in the `a + b` copy of `b` is passed to `a.operator+`. At the end of the function this copy is destroyed.

So, to sum up:

- Your statement `c = a + b;` can be separated in two parts:

  ```
  temp = a + b;
  c = temp;
  ```
- The first statement is basically this:

  ```
  temp = a.operator+(b);
  ```

Now, your `operator+` is receiving `param` by value. This means that copy of object `b` will be created and you will have two identical objects: `b` and `param`. When this function returns, `param` object will be destroyed.

Now, everything would be good **except**:

- Even `b` and `param` are separated objects, their pointers `width` and `height` points to a single memory location. Destructor of `param` will free this memory and `b`'s pointers will point to deallocated memory locations. In order to prevent this, you need to write copy-constructor:

  ```
  CRectangle::CRectangle(const CRectangle& param) {
      width = new int;  // alocate separate memory locations!
      height = new int; 
      *width =  *param.width;
      *height = *param.height;
  }
  ```

To avoid copy-on-passing, pass by const-reference instead:

```
CRectangle CRectangle::operator+ (const CRectangle &param)
```

As you noted, the same thing happens with `operator=`.

Also, this code:

```
temp.width = new int;
temp.height = new int;
*temp.width = *width + *param.width;
*temp.height = *height + *param.height;
```

can be rewritten as (also the types of `width` and `height` should be changed to `int`):

```
temp.width = width + param.width
temp.height = height + param.height;
```

There's no need to have pointers as fields in your class, if they serve just like regular values.

Comment: but it would receive the copy of temp right. why b is deleted?

Comment: @AkshatAggarwal `b` is not deleted Copy of the `b` is deleted - see my edit for more explanation.

Comment: see i have an area function which multiplies width and height.
So, if i call it on b before c=a+b, it gives 30, but after it gives a random value. If the copy is deleted, why is that happening?

See the edit

Comment: ok got it thanks :) i think what is happening is, when i m deleting the copy, it is also deleting the height and width pointer's data. So there are returning random values

Comment: You need to write down copy-constructor, so it would create separate memory on copy. Or you may just not use pointers here.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're not passing a const-reference to the operator function (and you should be). Also the function should be `const` too:

```
CRectangle CRectangle::operator+ (const CRectangle &param) const {...}
```